# How to use Related Tags to categorize products in a website based on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tags, categories

I'm trying to use a crazy method for categorizing products in my website. I'm thinking of a "tag based" category system. In this method, each keyword or tag is like a star.

In my mind the main advantage of this method is to not have any repeated keywords / tags.

Let's take `Apparel` as example:

```
ID  Related Tag ID  (Name - Seperate Table)
1   0       Apparel
2   1       Men
3   1       Women
4   1       Shirt
5   1       T-Shirt
6   1       Big Size

4   6       Shirt
5   6       T-Shirt

4   2       Shirt
5   2       T-Shirt

4   3       Shirt
5   3       T-Shirt
```

- By choosing a tag, eg `Shirt`, a list of all other tags related to it will appear as sub-categories: Apparel, Men, Women, Big Size. And by choosing each of them, other related tags will be offered...
- To not have loop, if a branch includes any previously added tag, it should be taken as leaf.

The main problem is normally the number of categories for the website I'm working on it are about 5000 and about 5 levels. By using `tag based category` this number will increase 10s times more. The questions are:

1. Is it logical to use this system?
2. Is it possible for MySQL to manipulate it?

Comment: 2nd question first: You can't do it with a simple query. You'd need a function or stored procedure.

1st question: If your tool is SQL, then it's based on the idea of separating related information in different table and create RELATIONS between them. Recursive categorization is a constant struggle with this tool for everyone. If you can have an algorithm that UNIQUELY identify a piece of information, then it's *logical*. The better question is "is it efficient to store and retrieve". That should be your defining goal.

Comment: Google ways to store hierarchical data in MySQL. There are some good articles on the topic on the web.